# Muultiple LAN on one layer 2 switch

Tags: networking, cisco

Is it possible to have more than one LAN on one Layer 2 switch  ? Please I need explanation for this ?

Comment: Of course it is for the correct type of switch, but you need to ask on the correct SE site. [networkengineering.se] or [sf] for a business network, or [su] for a personal network. [so] is for programming questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple vlans on a layer 2 switch using dot1q tagged vlans, regardless of whether or not the switch is vlan aware/managed switch.  One use case for this would be voip phones with a voice vlan configured.

In regards to a managed switch, you can of course configure vlan's on a managed switch.  All switches are technically layer-2, they are otherwise layer-3 switches, which have routing capability built in.

Comment: What happens to tagged frames on an unmanaged switch is undefined. Some will simply pass the frames on, some will drop the frames as damaged, and some will strip off the VLAN tag. Making a blanket statement that this works on unmanaged switches is reckless.